# How to execute a bash for loop via Java's runtime().exec() method

Tags: java, bash, shell, command

Basically, I've been having trouble executing a for loop when passing it through Java. It works when I enter directly into the console, as does "mkdir", "mv", "cp" etc. When I attempt to execute a for loop, it says it cannot find program "for".

the error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "for": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

loop ex:

```
for f in folder/*.filetype; do folder/scriptname $f > ${f}s; done
```

in java ex:

```
String s = "for f in folder/*.filetype; do folder/scriptname $f > ${f}s; done";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
```

After researching on here a bit I also tried:

```
String s = "for f in folder/*.filetype; do folder/scriptname $f > ${f}s; done";
String[] command = {s};
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
process.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
 }

process.waitFor();
int exitValue = process.exitValue();
process.destroy();
```

After trying it the way I found on here, the error changed to show the entire string, but still didn't run.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "for f in folder/filetype; do folder/scriptname $f > ${f}s; done": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

But I'll admit I'm pretty new and don't actually know what this is trying to do exactly.

Comment: You need to manually run it through a shell instead of directly as an executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commands like `for`, `mkdir` and `mv` are shell commands and require you to be in a shell when they are executed.

If you put the commands inside a file with the appropriate [hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the top and then invoke that from java it should work.

However, you can do the "for f in folder" part in pure java and then execute the script using ProcessBuilder